# log4j: how to output only messages I'm interesting in

Tags: java, log4j

When I setup log4j for a class, for example:

```
private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginAction.class);
```

with config

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, abc
log4j.appender.abc = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.abc.layout = org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
```

it will output all messagess info and warn even those from framework and something else I'm not interesting in. So, how output only my messages defined in code like:

```
log.warn("login error: " + email);
log.info("login success: " + email);
```

Comment: You can apply a filter, to only show all-info-debug ...
I have never configured it myself, so I can't go into details, but searching for "configuration Log level log4j" should get you quite some information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `log4j.rootLogger = INFO, abc` to `log4j.rootLogger = ERROR, abc` and build another logger for your package with loglevel `info`

```
log4j.logger.<your package>= INFO, abc
```

Comment: it works but output all messages twice
`log4j.rootLogger = ERROR, abc
log4j.appender.abc = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.abc.layout = org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout

log4j.logger.ru.user.action = INFO, abc`

Comment: @Andy Then add `log4j.additivity.ru.user.action=false`. This should help.